# Where do I find the translation overview?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm totally spooked about this. Last week I activated the contributed module [Translation Overview](http://drupal.org/project/translation_overview). All worked great, a very usefull module for my project. Now, one week later, I'm totally unable to find this translation overview in Drupal. I have searched every corner, browsed the web to no avail, I have all permissions, the module is activated...

**Where do I find the translation overview?**

Comment: Found it: ?q=admin/config/content/translation-overview-manage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the translation overview on:

*admin/config/content/translation-overview-manage*